# endIcon vs passwordToggle in TextInputLayout Android

Tags: android, xml

I got some trouble when I confused between "endIcon vs passwordToggle in TextInputLayout Android"
What differences of their ?
For instance :

**endIcon**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_password"
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/password_icon"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle">
```

**passwordToggle**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_password"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/password_icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"` and you don't override `app:passwordToggleDrawable=` you get 2 things for free

1. Any inner `EditText` will automatically toggle between the password shown and hidden state when the password icon is tapped
2. When toggling the visibility the user will see an animation between the 2 password icon states

Comment: Ok I got it, but I want to change the icons to my liking. How to do that ?